# Use share_from_this instead of this pointer

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I want to generate a shared_ptr from a class and use it instead of the this* raw pointer to initialize another one. The other expects a shared_ptr in Constructor. I'm showing only a excerpt:

```
class Soundfile : std::enable_shared_from_this<Soundfile> { ...more code

std::shared_ptr<Soundfile> Soundfile::getptr() {
     return  shared_from_this();
}
```

I need to initialize another class called Channel inside from Soundfile:

```
bool Soundfile::openRead(const char *filename_) { 
//more code ...
     channels = std::make_shared<Channel>(getptr() , windowSize_, gdata);
}
```

This doesn't works, I become a weak_ptr exception, I tried to do the following:

```
std::shared_ptr<Soundfile> Soundfile::getptr() {
    try {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
    catch (const std::bad_weak_ptr&) {
        return std::make_shared<Soundfile>();
    }
}
```

This works, but I become a new empty shared_ptr, I saved previously data inside the class Soundfile, I need to use it inside Channel, for this reason that is not what I'm looking for. 
I searched for a solution here, but I couldn't find one, sorry if the question is duplicated

EDIT:
Here is a minimal example what I'm trying to explain:

```
class A : std::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
public:
    A() {}
    ~A() {}
    std::shared_ptr<A> getptr() {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
    void my_method() {
        myB = std::make_shared<B>(getptr());
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<B> myB;
};

class B {
public:
    B(std::shared_ptr<A> _myA)  {
        myA = _myA;
    }
    ~B() {}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<A> myA;
};

int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<A> myA = std::make_shared<A>();
    myA->my_method();

}
```

Comment: How is `Soundfile` instance created? `shared_from_this()` only works on an instance currently managed by a `shared_ptr`

Comment: Soundfile is created in another class, in the following way, `std::shared_ptr<Soundfile> file = std::make_shared<Soundfile>();`  `file->openRead(audiofile);` Channel is created inside the method openRead

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://rextester.com/ZBG20971). The problem likely lies somewhere in the code you haven't shown. For further assistance, prepare and show a [mcve].

Comment: Yes, I now, the classes are big, I can't copy the whole class here. NO the error is in this point, at the moment where the class channel is initialized inside the method `sound file->openRead`  As I pointed out i change the method getptr in the following way `std::shared_ptr<Soundfile> Soundfile::getptr() {
    try {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
    catch (const std::bad_weak_ptr&) {                
        return std::shared_ptr<Soundfile> temp (this);;        
    }
}` now the initialization from Channel works, but I'm not sure if this way is safe

Comment: Most likely, this means that the instance on which `openRead` is called is *not* managed by a `shared_ptr` after all, despite your assurances to the contrary.

Comment: openRead is created inside the main class, inside this method I have to instantiate the class channel, in order to create it i have to give a this* pointer from the class Soundfile, inside it. Soundfile is mananged by a shared_ptr inside the main class, not inside itself

Comment: Once again - rather than attempting to describe your code in prose, prepare a [mcve]. I'm afraid I am unable to assist you further until I see one.

Comment: I posted a minimal example

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/TPT36898). What was this example supposed to demonstrate?

Comment: @Luis Just to be clear, what you are doing is **not safe**. You are giving ownership over `Soundfile` to the `shared_ptr` without removing it from whoever owned it first. Once the original owner deletes the object, you will get undefined behaviour that most likely results in crashes. Find out what is wrong with your code! The object is *not* owned by a `shared_ptr` (or your environment is broken, less likely). Maybe you are calling that method on a copy of the object by accident?

Comment: @MarkusMayr yes, it is not safe, I become an error when the class is closing, an error in destructor. Is the only option to use a this* raw pointer instead of a shared_ptr?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this is a minimal example, I'm trying to demonstrate where is the problem. As MarkusMayr pointed out, that is not safe.

Comment: Well, it's minimal, and reasonably complete, but not *verifiable*. It doesn't exhibit the problem you claim you are having.

Answer (score 4):

`std::enable_shared_from_this::shared_from_this` only works if the instance is currently managed by a shared pointer.

You can think of `enable_shared_from_this` as a class that contains a `weak_ptr`. When passing an instance of a class that is derived from `std::enable_shared_from_this` to the `shared_ptr` constructor, that constructor will initialize the `weak_ptr` inside it. Calling `shared_from_this` will only work after the weak pointer has been initialized, because it is implemented by converting that `weak_ptr` to a `shared_ptr`.

If you call `shared_from_this` before the `weak_ptr` has been initialized, it will raise a `bad_weak_ptr` exception, because the cast to a `shared_ptr` fails.

In order to solve your problem, you have to make sure that any instance of Soundfile is managed by a `shared_ptr` before the `getptr()` method or any method calling it is called.

In those rare cases were I use `shared_from_this`, I usually make the constructors private and add static factory methods in order to enforce this:

```
class A {
    public:
        static std::shared_ptr<A> create() {
            return std::make_shared<A>();
        }
    private:
        A();
};
```

You still have to be careful what you are doing in your constructors, because `shared_from_this` won't work inside them.

Comment: Yes, I know shared_from_this has to be managed for a shared_ptr. The problems that I have to use a shared_ptr in a class memeber in order to initialize another class. If possible I don't want to use the *this pointer to dow that. I found a solution, but I don't know if it is not "dirty":   `std::shared_ptr<Soundfile> Soundfile::getptr() {
    try {
        return shared_from_this();
    }
    catch (const std::bad_weak_ptr&) {
        return std::shared_ptr<Soundfile> temp (this);        
      }
  }`